# Springboot with Graphql error with "Consider defining a bean of type '{component name}' in your configuration."

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, javabeans, spring-boot-test

I am using Spring boot with graphql and rest.
While adding graphql component I used annotation like this.

Controller

```
@Controller // <------ with this annotation
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class AController( 
    @Autowired val aRepository: ARepository,
    @Autowired val aService: AService
){
 ...
}
```

Service

```
@Service // <------ with this annotation
class AService (
{
 ...
}
```

Repository

```
@GraphQlRepository
interface ARepository: JpaRepository<A, Long> {
```

But got these errors

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '{component name}' in your configuration.
```

It only happens when using test

```
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
internal class ControllerTest {
    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    fun healthCheck() {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/healthcheck"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk).andExpect(
                content().string("healthy")
            ).andDo(print())
    }
}
```

I understand I can use ComponentSacn but I want to know why this happend.
Because this package was place along with other components witch @ComponentScanner works well.

My structure is like this.
material works well while it cannot scan bakeryReview
[image]

I think I used component annotations okay, and package structure is okay.  Maybe test is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!!  There's nothing wrong with annotation nor structure.
For those who see this question, It was **`WebMvcTest`**. `WebMvcTest` needs component to be mocked, because it only injects web-related components like @Controller. So it omits other components like @Service or @Repository.

I added these and it works okay.

```
@MockBean
lateinit var aService: AService

@MockBean
lateinit var aRepository: ARepository
```